# How to create additional fields and remove them from a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, pug

I am trying to allow users to add additional email fields if they want to add additional email accounts, and hit remove if they hit they do not want to add the field. However, I  cannot get the remove button to work, and I was also, trying to somehow differentiate each class by including a variable emailCount in each class but that is not working either for some reason...

Here is the jquery script: (it is in a document ready function)

```
  var i = 0;
 $(function(){       
        i =+ 1;
        var emailCount = "Email" + i.toString();
        console.log(i);
        console.log(emailCount);
        $('.addEmail').click(function() {


            $('#addInfo').append('<div class="' + emailCount '"></div><form class="newEmail", method="post", action="newEmailPost"> <label>' + emailCount + '</label>' + '<input name="' + emailCount + '", type="email", value=""/><br><input type="submit", class="addNewEmail", value="Save Email"></input><button class="removeEmailField">Remove</button></form><br>');
        });

         $('.removeEmailField').click(function() {
            $(emailCount).remove();

        });
    });
```

Here is the jade file: (it works correctly, but maybe it will help for visual purposes)

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent
        div
            form.validateForm(method="POST", action="/editUserProfile")
                    legend Edit Profile
                    input(type="text", name="firstName", maxlength="20", placeholder=ufirstName, value=ufirstName)
                    br
                    input(type="text", name="lastName", maxlength="20", placeholder=ulastName, value=ulastName)
                    br
                    input(type="email", name="email", maxlength="20", placeholder=uemail, value=uemail)
                    br
                    - if(uemailList.length > 0)
                        for userC in uemailListCount
                            for userE in uemailList
                                input(type="email", name=userC, maxlength="20", placeholder=userE, value=userE)
                                br
                    input(type="number", name="phone", maxlength="20", placeholder=uphone, value=uphone)
                    br
                    input(type="date", name="birthday", value=ubirthday)
                    br
                    input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", name="Update", value="Save")
                    a(href="/userProfile")
                        button.btn(type="button") Cancel
                    hr
        div#addInfo
            label Add another email address:  
                button.addEmail Add Email
            br
            label Add another phone number:  
                button.addPhone Add Phone Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("."+emailCount).remove();
i--;
```

If you want to add or remove several times make sure the emailCount is set with the right value, when adding you're not setting it again and when removing you're not changing i as well.

Comment: I am actually getting an error for the .append line of code uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to convert emailcount to a class format in the remove function.  Something like:

```
var classifiedEmailCount = "." + emailCount;
$(stringifiedEmailCount).remove();
i--;
```

Comment: Yeah, see comment above, I am getting some error for my code, not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just changed it around a bit like this:

```
$('.addEmail').click(function() {
            $('#addInfo').replaceWith('<div class="newEmailAdd"></div><form class="newEmail", method="post", action="/newEmailPost"> <label> Add Another Email </label>' + '<input name="emailNew", type="email", value=""/><br><input type="submit", class="addNewEmail", value="Save Email"></input><button class="removeEmailField">Remove</button></form><br>');
        });



 $('.removeEmailField').click(function() {
            alert('You clicked remove');
            $('.newEmailAdd').remove();

  });
```

I did not need the multiple fields to work anymore.